# How to invert image for OCR?

Tags: autohotkey

Using the: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/69127-ocrahk-library-for-recognizing-text-in-images/ library, using djpeg.exe, how does one **invert** an image taken by OCR? Currently i'm  recieving from the source: **white** text on a dark background, but since the background is variable but always dark i'd like to **invert** the image for possible better results.

Comment: I think increasing contrast would be a better choice, but without you providing any samples, no one will be able to make an educated guess. Also, this question isn't very specific to AHK, please add more accurate tags like [tag:ocr] or [tag:image-processing].

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the example in the post right here : http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/72462-how-to-invert-color-in-a-jpeg-picture/?p=486171